# How to connect wireless Xbox 360 controller with USB?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I got non-rechargeable AA batteries in my pack with wireless controller. Now the batteries have drained out. I want to know can I connect the wireless controller to Xbox 360 via USB cable?

Comment: No nothing to do with PC

Comment: Sorry, I'm clearly way too tired to be casting close votes right now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xbox 360 controller has got a power cable, but unfortunately it's a proprietary one.

[image: Xbox 360 Plug and Charge Kit]

You will need the cable from a [Plug and Charge kit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Official-Xbox-360-Play-Charge/dp/B003VD56K2) (pictured above) for 360 controllers in order to use the controller without batteries.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the "Plug and Charge Kit", as mentioned by Jeeva, but really, with the cost of that, plus shipping, plus some rechargeable batteries, I wonder if it might not just be cheaper to buy a second, **wired**, controller.

At least then you could play two player games should you ever want to.